# Where is 5th positional argument coming from?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript, jsii

Having:

```
class PythonCdkProjectStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        test = kms.KeyProps(alias = "HALLO")
        test1 = sns.TopicProps()

        try = CustomConstruct(self, "MyId", test, test1)
```

Throws:

```
TypeError: CustomConstruct.__init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

I can only see 4 arguments going into the constructor. Where is the 5th argument that is send into the constructor coming from?

The construct has been transpiled into Python using jsii and jsii-pacmak. The constructer signature in Typescript is:

```
constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, keyProps: kms.KeyProps, sns.TopicProps)
```

The weirdest part to me is that is I change the signature to:

```
constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, keyProps: kms.KeyProps, sns.TopicProps, test: string)
```

And then call the constructor from Python using `CustomConstruct(self, "MyId", test, test1, "test")` everything works fine.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε how would that answer it? The Python class is not what is instantiated.

Comment: I see an error talking about 5 when 4 were expected, and you speaking about 5 and 6th arguments. So I am even more confused with your comment, tbh.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε 5 should be 4 and 6 should be 5 (typing mistake). However my comment is not that confusing. The class that is instantiated is a class written in Typescript and packed with pacmak for use in a Python cdk project.